# Android use of resources from an external file

Tags: android

I have a non-standard Android application that has a requirement to load resources from an external file that is not part of the application apk.  These resources will be packaged separately and delivered as its own package.

There are a few different types of items that will be part of this external resource bundle.  One of those items includes the localized strings.xml file.  This philosophy allows the change of a string / translation that does not affect the deployment of the application (in other words, application.apk stays in tact, but the only difference is a new strings.xml).

I've been searching around, and this doesn't seem possible.  Is there any way?  Or does this philosophy mean completely abandoning the resources all together and writing a custom layer to pull these strings and other external resources from a file?

The application is for Honeycomb platform.

Thanks in advance for any advise.

Comment: how have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, I think, is to package your resources as a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). See the guide topic [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for how to get started doing this.